# Help with a chat python application

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am currently making a chat application in python. I am having 2 separate codes: one for the server and one for the client. The server script is taking the login data of new clients that connects and in another thread manages the messages that he has to receive and send.

The client application is made into a class and works well, excepts that when the script requests the UI to show, the only new window is a empty one:

```
def __init__(self, master):
    self.nr=0
    self.frameul=self.tbox=self.txt=self.scrollbar=self.button=self.roottk=[0]*20
    self.OameniSiIduri={}
    self.LoginUI(master)
    self.framestate=""

def ChatUI(self, peer_id):

    no=self.no
    self.no+=1

    self.PeoplesAndId[peer_id]=no
    self.base[no]=Toplevel()

    self.theframe[no] = Frame(self.base[no])
    self.theframe[no].pack()

    self.entry[no] = Entry(self.theframe[no], width=95)
    self.tbox[no] = Text(self.theframe[no], state=DISABLED, wrap=WORD)
    self.button[no] = Button(self.theframe[no], text="Send", fg="green", command=lambda x=self.entry[no].get(), y=peer_id, z=self.tbox[nr]: self.Sendmsg(x,y,z), width=10)

    self.tbox[no].pack(side=TOP, fill=X)
    self.button[no].pack(side=RIGHT)
    self.entry[no].pack(side=LEFT)
    .....
```

All the vars and the functions are declared. Can anyone give me a hint about what can the cause of this problem is?

Comment: Have you called a `mainloop()`?

Comment: yep, i have added everything needed. As I said, the second window appears but it's empty (mint 11, python 2.6)

Comment: Other than the `x`, `y`, and `z` parameters passed to the button, it works perfectly for me.

Comment: I could post the whole code, but part of it is in some other language (vars and strings mostly)

Comment: That might help, thanks. If you don't want to post the whole class, just `__init__` should do (but the posting the whole class would make it even simpler to debug).

Comment: As i said, the code has vars and string in other languages, but here it is

Comment: @Serban Razvan: your "EDIT" section is unclear -- does that `__init__` go with the above code? If so, just add it to the code. The way you have the edit below the class is confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found myself the mistake after searching all the night through the code. Apparently if i use this line:

```
self.theframe=self.tbox=self.entry=self.scrollbar=self.button=self.base=[0]*20
```

All the objects point to the same value.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is, the code that is creating the UI is throwing an error that you are not seeing. For example, are you importing `DISABLED` and `WORD` properly? If not, the code would fail after creating the frame but before creating the other widgets, leaving you with an empty widget.

One way to debug this is to give each toplevel and frame a distinct color. This lets you see which are visible and which are not -- maybe you're looking at a window or frame and thinking it's one thing when it's something else.

Comment: Found myself the solution after some debugging in IDLE but thanks for the answer